# The three images overlap on the jquery effect

Tags: jquery

```
 <div class="container">
 <div class="page-header">
 <h1><strong>Manga To Read</strong></h1>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="container" id="manga">
 <div class="row">
 <!--One Piece-->
 <div id="firstStar" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
 <a href="#">
 <img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" src="http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130115020528/onepiece/images/0/0e/Volume_1.png" />
 </a>
 <h3><strong>One Piece</strong></h3>
 </div>
 <!--One Piece end-->
 <!--Bleach-->
 <div id="secondStar"class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
 <a href="#">
 <img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" src="http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/bleach/images/a/ad/MangaVolume1Cover.png/revision/latest?cb=20141201173531&path-prefix=en" />
 </a>
 <h3><strong>Bleach</strong></h3>
 </div>
 <!--Bleach end-->
 <!--Naruto-->
 <div id="thirdStar" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
 <a href="#">
 <img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/71T54zlToTL.jpg" />
 </a>
 <h3><strong>Naruto</strong></h3>
 </div>
 <!--Naruto End-->
 </div>
 </div>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $("#firstStar").animate({left:200, opacity:"show"}, 1500);  
    $("#secondStar").animate({bottom:200, opacity:"show"}, 1500);
    $("#thirdStar").animate({right:200, opacity:"show"}, 1500);
 });

 });
```

These images are overlapping when scrolling. I want the image on the left to fade in from left, the middle image to fade in from bottom and the image on the right to fade in from right. Any help?
[Demo](http://codepen.io/Ashirogi-Muto/full/vLebxz/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understand all. [Here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MKExBB) is my demo.

I changed js and add some css:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        $("#firstStar").animate({left:0, opacity:"show"}, 1500);  
        $("#secondStar").animate({bottom:0, opacity:"show"}, 1500);
        $("#thirdStar").animate({right:0, opacity:"show"}, 1500);
    });

});
```

and

```
#firstStar{
    left: -200px;
}

#secondStar{
    bottom: -200px;
}

#thirdStar{
    right: -200px;
}
```

Comment: This is what I wanted. Thanks a lot